# Interact with embedded Dailymotion (DMCloud) iframe video?

Tags: iframe, dailymotion-api

When displaying a Dailymotion (DMCloud) video in an iframe on my page, how can I use JavaScript to interact with video - get current playing time, for example?

Dailymotion have a JS SDK for this ([docs](http://developer.dailymotion.com/documentation#sdk-javascript)), but I can't find how to use the SDK to interact with an existing iframe rather than create a new one.

So, assuming I have something like:

```
<iframe src="https://api.dmcloud.net/embed/4e5bf73e94a6f629c900461b/4fcbcc1a06361d0dda000267?auth=1571064530-0-6tpgjq7u-30443abdac10acef6cf336eb89412713&amp; id="foo"></iframe>
```

Using JS, how can I get the current playing time of the video?

Answer (score 2):

it looks like your are mixing DM cloud and Dailymotion.com 
The APIs are different and the documentation for the cloud player can be found at https://www.dmcloud.net/doc/api/player-video_player.html

There is a working example at the bottom of the page: http://api.dmcloud.net/static/dmplayer/dmplayer-sdk.html

Anyway, I think you're missing the code you're refering to but I confirm you cannot control or interact with an iframe that wasn't created using the API.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, for some reason the code was missing. It's too bad you can't interact with an existing iframe.. we might resort to manually recreating the iframe using DM.player, which is kind of silly but is the most straightforward way to go. Any chance DM.player can expose that functionality instead..? That is, parse the iframe and re-create it this time retaining control?

Comment: No, that can't be exposed, why don't you create the iframe on your website/app using the api in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems possible @Dailymotion, the iframe needs to be loaded with &api=postMessage, then you get a DOM reference to the iframe and do:

```
iframe.contentWindow.postMessage('play', '*');
```

And it works.